# Force RTL or LTR in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I know SwiftUI changes the direction of the application, based on the system language of the device. but is there a way to ignore the system language and force the app to be always RTL or LTR?

Comment: If I got it right, it might depend on how you set the view/container views. I'd prefer to provide an example of some minimal code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can either set layout direction in the Scene Delegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

or manually disable change of direction on some views using this modifier:

```
.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
```

Comment: thanks. The first option worked, but only ContentView file. is there a way to set RTL mode for the whole application?

Comment: Can you see this behaviour in the previews or on simulator/ device as well? I have noticed that previews don't pick up environment variables set up in the scene delegate, but they work as expected when you run the app.

Comment: no it doesn't, but it does when I add the same ContentView().environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft) in the preview struct.

Comment: I guess you have to manually add it to every view then - quite similar to UIKit actually. On the other hand what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 29):

You may one to make the app default language to some **Right To Left** like `Persian` in `info.plist` or with other methods:

[image: Info.plist]

---

If you need to force a view, Just apply this modifier on any view you like:

```
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

You can apply to the `ContentView()` in `SceneDelegate` to make it available for all subviews.

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything to force SwiftUI to be RTL Arabic, Like...

```
import SwiftUI

    @main
    struct MyApp: App {
        init() {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        }
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
             
                ContentView()
                    .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))
                    .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            }
        }
    }
```

But this way cause a lot of bugs if you use NavigationView
The best solution is...

```
import SwiftUI

    @main
    struct MyApp: App {
        init() {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        }
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
             
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```