# How to set RTL or LTR mode and layout direction for the whole application by tapping on button in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to set RTL or LTR mode and layout direction for the whole application not to any specific view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force RTL or LTR in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844571/force-rtl-or-ltr-in-swiftui)

Comment: @RonakPatel I tried that, however it only worked for one view, not the entire application.