# Changing the TextField direction according the keyboard language in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

The default direction for the TextField is LTR. I want it to change to RTL automatically when the user changes the keyboard language to Arabic, and of course back to LTR when the keyboard language is changed to English.

This is my code in SwiftUI

```
TextField("Type here ...", text: $text)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
```

Alos I want to change the text "Type here ..." to something in Arabic if possible.

[image: screen shot]

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844571/force-rtl-or-ltr-in-swiftui

Comment: I want the direction to change automatically according to the keyboard language.

Comment: That would be a multi stage process I don’t think there is an easy way